# Error al mostrar excepción personalizada en C++

Tags: c++

Estaba creando una excepción personalizada en c++ para el programa que estoy creando, es un intérprete y una excepción que necesito crear es la de `EOL Error` entre otras. Hice mi archivo de cabecera y mi archivo `.cpp`. Hice la implementación y sobrecarga de los métodos necesarios y todo bien hasta el momento de lanzar la excepción y capturarla. Voy dejando parte del código.

**Exceptions.h**

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace Exceptions
{
    class EOLError : public std::exception
    {
    private:
        int linea;
        std::string message;
    public:
        EOLError();
        EOLError(int num_linea, string linea);
        const char * what() const throw();
    };
}
```

**Exceptions.cpp**

```cpp
#include "Exceptions.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace Exceptions;
using namespace std;
EOLError::EOLError(){}

EOLError::EOLError(int linea, string msg){
    this->linea = linea;
    message = msg;
}

const char* EOLError::what() const throw(){
    string msg = string(to_string(linea)) + " | " + message;
    return msg.c_str();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "Exceptions.cpp"

int main(){
    try
    {
        int num_linea = 1;
        string linea = "var = \"hola\"";
        if(linea[linea.size() - 1] != ';') throw EOLError(num_linea, linea);

    }
    catch(const exception& e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Al mostrar la excepción me salen cosas raras en la consola, practicamente como si fuera basura, pero si agrego un `cout << msg;` antes del return me muestra el mensaje.

Lo que debería mostrar sería esto:

```
1 | var = "hola"
```

¿Qué debería hacer para que el mensaje se me muestre correctamente? ¿Acaso no puedo crear variables en ese método?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tu error es muy sencillo:

```
const char* EOLError::what() const throw(){
    string msg = string(to_string(linea)) + " | " + message;
    return msg.c_str();
}
```

Ahí estas creando una variable *automática* `msg`. Y utilizas un dato de esa variable como el dato que devuelves ... con la característica de que el dato en cuestión es un puntero gestionado por la propia variable `msg`: el `string` se encarga de gestionar esa memoria ... y de liberarla cuando sea necesario.

Las variables automáticas tienen un tiempo de vida limitado, asociado a su ámbito. En tu caso, la variable `msg` **deja de existir** al llegar al `return` ... y entonces realiza todas las operaciones indicadas en su destructor, entre ellas la liberación de cualquier memoria usada internamente ...

Y llegamos al desenlace: lo que recibes fuera, es un puntero a una zona de memoria gestionada por una variable que ya no existe ... y que ya no contiene lo que esperas. Y cualquier intento de acceder a esa posición es comportamiento indefinido.

La solución mas simple es que realices esa operación **en tu propio constructor**, con lo cual no necesitarás crear esa variable *al vuelo*:

```
EOLError::EOLError(int linea, string msg){
    message = to_string( linea ) + " | " + msg;
}

const char* EOLError::what() const throw(){
    return message.c_str();
}
```

Y con eso ya no te hace falta la variable-miembro `linea` en tu `EOLError`.

Comment: De verdad, a veces se me cruzan los cables. Gracias